# Join multiple objects then split into a set number?

Tags: objects, vertices, obj

Am pretty new to blender and still learning my way through it all but have a question that I'm unable to find the answer to.

I have a model I'm trying to import with 24 objects. Each model has 200 vertices but for a project I'm trying to complete, I need the models to be 12 objects only.

Is there a way to join all the objects together then split them up into a set number of objects? In this case, I'd choose 12 objects, etc. Each object would have to be 200 vertices. In other words, the current model is 24 objects with a total of 4,800 vertices. I'd like that model to be 12 objects with a total of 2,400 vertices.

I'm not sure if this is possible but thought I would ask as it would save me a lot of time having to re-do each object to essentially double each one until I have only 12. Need the vertices number to remain at 12.

Don't care how the model would be split, as long as it's only 12 objects at 200 vertices each.

Thanks

Comment: I fully understand the model quality will drop given it's half the vertices but that's fine. Just wondering if this is possible as for what I'm doing, the model fails when I use anything over 12 objects and 200 vertices for each object.

Comment: Automatically would be ideal instead of having to separate anything manually.